# Sinatra requests time out after filling a SQLite table

Tags: sqlite, sinatra, datamapper

I'm trying to debug this literally for hours now, and I just don't make any progress. I'm using DataMapper as an ORM, and SQLite as the DB system:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite:db.sqlite')
```

I got two models `User` and `Game`. When I add fields to the first model everything works fine. As soon as I add a field to `Game` (via Sinatra route or IRB), all the HTTP requests to Sinatra time out. All of them, including those to static assets. I can still access all database information  via IRB (`Game.all`).

When I empty the database (`DataMapper.auto_migrate!`) and restart the server (shotgun + thin) everything works fine again.

I understand that it's probably hard to answer this, but nothing throws any errors, and I don't know how to debug this anymore, so I'd appreciate if you guys could point me in the right direction.

---

That's the `Game` model:

```
class Game
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :active, Boolean, default: true
  property :players, Object

  property :name, String, required: true
  property :size, Integer
  property :filled_size, Integer, default: 1
end
```

Maybe I'm using some type that SQLite doesn't support?

Comment: When the server ties up, have you tried accessing the sqlite console and seeing if the data has been added successfully? It'd also be helpful if you're able to share the code for the route where the `Game` data gets added.

Comment: What's in the :players property? Have you tried without it? If you want this to be a foreign key to the User table you need to do it differently.

Comment: Also, you can use datamapper outside of the context of Sinatra/web application. Try the model in a standalone ruby script and test some basic operations like creating the databased, inserting records, finding records, deleting records, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this!

I pushed my app to heroku to see if it's some local problem. When the app crashed on heroku I got a stack trace as the response of my AJAX request, I didn't get one locally (should be the other way around, I know). The problem was that I was calling `to_json` on a DataMapper model. I'm now using [dm-serializer](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-serializer), and it works fine.